# Why does create_association not work on a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have this association setup:

```
class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connections, dependent: :destroy
end
```

But, when I try to do the following:

```
@membership ||= Membership.find_or_create_by(member: @member)
@connection ||= @membership.create_connection!(sent_at: Time.now, times_sent: 1, request_status: 0)
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `create_connection!' for #<Membership:0x007fab2dac83b8>
```

Despite the fact that the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) say I should be able to do this:

```
belongs_to(name, scope = nil, options = {}) Link

Methods will be added for retrieval and query for a single associated object, for which this object holds an id:

association is a placeholder for the symbol passed as the name argument, so belongs_to :author would add among others author.nil?.

create_association(attributes = {})
Returns a new object of the associated type that has been instantiated with attributes, linked to this object through a foreign key, and that has already been saved (if it passed the validation).

create_association!(attributes = {})
Does the same as create_association, but raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid if the record is invalid.
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your relations mixed up a bit. You've linked the docs for `belongs_to`. Since connection belongs to membership, you'd be able to

```
@membership ||= @connection.create_membership(attr1: val1, attr2: val2)
```

However, a **membership does not belong to a connection**. A membership has many connections. Scrolling down to [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), you can see that to build an association, you need to use:

```
collection.create(attributes = {}, …)
```

Applying that to your use case, you'd get

```
@connection || = @member.connections.create(sent_at: Time.now, times_sent: 1, request_status: 0)
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it seems the Rails 4 docs are out of date.

What I should be doing is:

```
@membership.connections.create!(sent_at: Time.now, times_sent: 1, request_status: 0)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The docs aren't out of date (well, they very well could be, but in this case they aren't), you're just mixing things up a bit. Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837940/2856441).